# iOS Multitask App Switcher Custom Image

Tags: ios, objective-c

im developing an iOS App and i would like it to behave like PayPal when the user double taps the home button.

For those who dont know the PayPal app displays a custom image when the app is displayed on the multitask switcher but it doesnt when a notification arrives or when the user pulls the notifications bar.

My issue comes when implementing this, im using the event applicationWillResignActive to display my custom image (as applicationEnteredBackground is not called for this). But this method is called on events on which i dont want the app to display the image (such as notifications, calls, pulling the top bar, etc).

Is there any way of setting this image only when the home button is double tapped?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, PayPal doesn't cover the viewport with a custom image immediately – when I double tap the Home button, it remains rendered normally until I do something else – but most probably on `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. After switching to Home screen or another application, the PayPal preview becomes covered.

On the other hand, my mobile banking application does that immediately when `applicationWillResignActive:` is triggered.

These are AFAIK the only two approaches you can achieve.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right. isnt there a way of filtering the events that call applicationWillResignActive? or at least know if it was triggered by an incoming notification or by pulling down the top bar? Thank you

Comment: Well I believe that's not possible. There are attempts to detect display of Control Centre by observing all `UIWindow` touches which could work with Notification Centre as well, you can try searching here on SO.