# Hide the screenshot in multitasking switcher only in particular cases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Chase bank's iOS app is showing blank view hiding apps details when double tap the home button from the app. And when you login inside the app and touchID alert appears the **apps view is not hidden** by blank view.

So far I can hide app details by showing image loaded on  `applicationWillResignActive` but it makes app hide it's details while touchID alert comes up.

I've checked similar questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111049/ios-multitask-app-switcher-custom-image). Also [here](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-control-the-preview-screenshot-in-the-ios-multitasking-switcher/). But there is no answer to my question. How to replicate Chase bank's app behavior? How not to hide app details with touchID alert, but have them hidden when double tapped the home button?

Comment: just add a check i think? check if the app is already logged in using touchid already or still in the login page to show the image

Comment: He's not asking for a check, he's asking for a way to hide the app's contents when the user presses the home button but not on another alert such as the Touch ID popup, which is why `applicationWillResignActive` doesn't work, because it will do the same on both of those events.

Comment: @EdwinFinch I dont really understand, it will always call there, thats what the check for, can actually choose what happen in `applicationWillResignActive`, can choose to show the image to hide the content or not

Comment: @AlexanderZ did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher)

Comment: @ricardopereira nope, it's not

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but couldn't find a valid answer to this exact question. So here's my solution.

steps:

1. create a instance variable for blocker view
2. init blocker view only once when it's necessary (I did it on `applicationWillResignActive`)
3. add blocker view as subview to the window at `applicationDidEnterBackground`
4. remove blocker view at `applicationWillEnterForeground`

Answer (score -1):

The app delegate's `applicationWillResignActive` is the right place where you put a black or whatever view you want to show when the app is being moved to background. You need to add the desired UIView on `Window` object. Also you need to remove that view when the app becomes active again.